# Replace 1 and 0 with strings in rendered table using vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, rendering, element

I am new to vue.
I am rendering a table using vue.js element.io framework. I am getting the data from the API. Everything works ok. Now I want to add text in 'Active' field. Active returns 1 or 0. I want to replace 1 and 0 with 'Active' and 'Inactive'. In Laravel I would do it like that:

```
{{($Active == 1)?'Active':'Inactive'}}
```

```js
  <el-table v-loading="loading" :data="result" @sort-change="sortChange">
                <el-table-column prop="FirstName" label="First name" sortable="custom"></el-table-column>
                <el-table-column prop="LastName" label="Last name" sortable="custom"></el-table-column>
                <el-table-column prop="Active" label="Status" sortable="custom"></el-table-column>
            </el-table>

end vue looks like:

 export default {
        name:"contacts",
        components: {
            'tinymce': VueEasyTinyMCE
        },
        data: function(){
            return {
                result: []
            };
        },
  }
```

Comment: you can look up the `custom column template` example here https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#custom-column-template

Comment: are you using laravel datatable to get data to your vue component?
if you are using yajra datatable then you can just edit the active column when creating datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the template using a custom column template. The data for the row is passed inot `scope.row`, so you can use that to get the data `scope.row.Active`, In the example, I"m expecting that the number will be either 1 or 0, which will be the truthy equivalent of true or false respectably, so a ternary operation is used to provide the Active/Inactive text

```
<el-table v-loading="loading" :data="result" @sort-change="sortChange">
  <el-table-column prop="FirstName" label="First name" sortable="custom"></el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="LastName" label="Last name" sortable="custom"></el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="Active" label="Status" sortable="custom"></el-table-column>

  <el-table-column label="Status" sortable="custom">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
      {{scope.row.Active?'Active':'Inactive'}}
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

You can also use a computed to do this conversion, by adding another bit of data, and keeping your template clean.

*note: I haven't tested the code, and looks like the syntax changed a bit since I last used Element*